# Is it neccessary to add the subject "she" in "and had"?

Tags: conjunctions, clauses

> Lisa used to be shy and have few friends.

> Lisa used to be shy and had few friends.

In the first example, **and** conects two infinitives **to be** and **to have**.

I think, in the second example, it is better to add the subject **she** to it.

> Lisa used to be shy and **she** had few friends.

Is it neccessary to add **she** to the second example?

Comment: Explicitly re-stating the subject by adding ***she***  before ***had*** in the second example is syntactically no different to explicitly repeating the infinitive marker in the first example: *...and **to** have few friends* (which could in principle be even more fully expanded to *...and **she used to** have few friends*). In both cases the highlighted elements are optional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not. All three sentences are perfectly good.

I can't find any clear difference in meaning among them

Comment: "All three sentences are perfectly good"—except that the last one, at least, should have a comma before "and," since "and" is joining two independent clauses in that sentence.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Is that some kind of reliable rule? I pulled books off the nearest shelf at random, and it was easy to find examples of the rule being broken by respected writers such as Graham Greene, Arundhati Roy, Daphne du Maurier, C L R James, Kazuo Ishiguro, and Iain Banks. (For what it's worth, I couldn't quickly find any counterexamples in a couple of books by Colin Dexter and by Philip Pullman.)

Comment: @JamesMartin There's this: https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/grammarpunct/coordconj/#:~:text=When%20a%20coordinating%20conjunction%20joins,never%20be%20followed%20by%20commas, but also this: https://www.google.com/amp/s/palimpsestediting.com/author-resources-punctuation-notes/when-to-omit-the-comma-before-the-coordinating-conjunction-that-joins-two-independent-clauses%3fformat=amp, so maybe it's not such a hard rule.